# Prevent 'Leave site?' dialog for Google Forms inside iframe?

Tags: vue.js

My Vue component uses Google Forms inside an iframe. The problem is, that when user tries to navigate to another page, she will get 'Leave site? Changes that you made may not be saved.' dialog. How can I disable this in my component?

EDIT: I noticed that this caused by the fact, that one field is prefilled on the google forms. Is there a way to bypass the dialog, if there a prefilled fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution. Add v-if the the iframe:

```
<iframe v-if=!hideGoogleForm" ...>
```

Then to mounted():

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  this.hideGoogleForm = true;
};
```

The dialog is still shortly shown but then automatically closed when the component is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I am spitballing here but I believe that the internal page inside the iframe sets an event handler for the window.beforeunload event, if your page does not use this event, you could

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function () {
          return undefined;
        };
```

Comment: I just noticed that this was caused by a prefilled field, however haven't found a way to bypass it so far.